# How to generate migrations based on existing tables in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I have a database and I would like to generate migration based on tables that already exists.

How can I do that?

I am running linux ubuntu 16.10 + Mariadb and laravel 5.4

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google shows many packages that will do just this sort of thing for you, like [`migrations-generator`](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator).

You'll probably want to go over any generated migrations as well just to make sure they match what you're after.